# Keep Options All -Indexes but allow access to a specific folder

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

How can I keep the `Options All -Indexes` but only allow access to a specific folder?
For example, allow access to /assets/elements

Also, does using Options All -Indexes prevent search engines from accessing these files and folders as well? so if we have images in /assets/images would Google find and access these images?

Comment: `Options -Indexes` **only** prevent listing of directory if there's no index file. So if you know path to a file, you can access it (same for search engines). If you want to disable it for a specific directory, you could create another htaccess in that directory and put this line `Options +Indexes`

Comment: oh, so this effects search engines as well?

Comment: Like i said, search engines (like simple users) **can** access a file in a directory if they **know** it. But if they go to that directory they won't see file listing

Comment: Allow /assets/elements and on the next row disable all. It should work - I think. Also works for robots.txt