# does Options All -Indexes in htaccess prevent search engines from indexing the files in a folder

Tags: .htaccess

At the risk of getting hit for a duplicate question, I typed my question in the title and read `all` of the questions/answers returned but I am still a bit confused.

I want to run Options All -Indexes in htaccess but I want to make sure that the search engines can index the images in the image gallery folders.

This question appeared to answer the question...

[Keep Options All -Indexes but allow access to a specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547426/keep-options-all-indexes-but-allow-access-to-a-specific-folder)

But then one of the answers stated that

`But if they go to that directory they won't see file listing`

Does this mean the files will no be able to be indexed because there is no index file, or does it mean the file can be indexed but the search engine simply will not see an index of the files?

Thanks in advance,
Pete

Answer (score 0):

If you block access to the directory listing, a search engine crawler cannot see the image files to index them,
UNLESS they are linked to by SOME accessible file that is visible.